# Find array intersection for each row in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe:

```
df_example = pd.DataFrame({'user1': ['u1', 'u1', 'u1', 'u5', 'u5', 'u5', 'u7','u7','u6'],
                           'user2': ['u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u2',  'u4','u6','u8','u3','u6']})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df_example)
userreposts_gr = sdf.groupby('user1').agg(F.collect_list('user2').alias('all_user2'))
userreposts_gr.show()
+-----+------------+
|user1|   all_user2|
+-----+------------+
|   u1|[u4, u2, u3]|
|   u7|    [u8, u3]|
|   u5|[u4, u2, u6]|
|   u6|        [u6]|
+-----+------------+
```

I want for each `user1` to see the intersections for `all_user2`.Create a new column that has the maximum intersection with the `user1`

```
+-----+------------+------------------------------+
|user1|all_user2   |new_col                       |
+-----+------------+------------------------------+
|u1   |[u2, u3, u4]|{max_count -> 2, user -> 'u5'}|
|u5   |[u2, u4, u6]|{max_count -> 2, user -> 'u1'}|
|u7   |[u8, u3]    |{max_count -> 1, user -> 'u1'}|
|u6   |[u6]        |{max_count -> 1, user -> 'u5'}|
+-----+------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: what if there are multiple users with the same maximum intersection with `user1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Cross join to find all the combination of `user1` pair

Step 2: Find the length of the intersected array

Step 3: Rank by the length and select the largest value in each user

```
output = userreposts_gr\
    .selectExpr(
        'user1', 'all_user2 AS arr1'
    ).crossJoin(
        userreposts_gr.selectExpr('user1 AS user2', 'all_user2 AS arr2')
    ).withColumn(
        'intersection', func.size(func.array_intersect('arr1', 'arr2'))
    )

output = output\
    .filter(
        func.col('user1') != func.col('user2')
    ).withColumn(
        'ranking', func.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('user1').orderBy(func.desc('intersection')))
    )

output = output\
    .filter(
        func.col('ranking') == 1
    ).withColumn(
        'new_col', func.create_map(func.lit('max_count'), func.col('intersection'), func.lit('user'), func.col('user2'))
    )

output = output\
    .selectExpr(
        'user1', 'arr1 AS all_user2', 'new_col'
    )

output.show(100, False)
+-----+------------+----------------------------+
|user1|all_user2   |new_col                     |
+-----+------------+----------------------------+
|u1   |[u2, u3, u4]|{max_count -> 2, user -> u5}|
|u5   |[u2, u4, u6]|{max_count -> 2, user -> u1}|
|u6   |[u6]        |{max_count -> 1, user -> u5}|
|u7   |[u8, u3]    |{max_count -> 1, user -> u1}|
+-----+------------+----------------------------+
```